# Android changing color of TextView in SimpleExpandableListAdapter

Tags: java, android

I am working on Android project. I need help with some error. I am trying to change text color in List. It fails with error:

05-16 15:15:19.867: E/AndroidRuntime(31408): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-16 15:15:19.867: E/AndroidRuntime(31408): java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.TwoLineListItem cannot be cast to android.widget.TextView

```
try {
    mAdapter = new SimpleExpandableListAdapter(
        this,
        groupData,
        android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_2,
        new String[] { FIRST, SECOND },
        new int[] { android.R.id.text1, android.R.id.text2 },
        childData,
        android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_2,
        new String[] { FIRST, SECOND },
        new int[] { android.R.id.text1, android.R.id.text2 }){
            @Override
            public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition,
                    boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

                TextView tv =  (TextView) super.getChildView(groupPosition, childPosition, isLastChild,convertView, parent);
                //change color text of tv here
                //tv.setTextColor(0xff00ff00);
                return tv;
            }
    };
    setListAdapter(mAdapter);
    getExpandableListView().setOnChildClickListener(this);
}
catch(Exception exc) {
    Log.e("Log", exc.toString());
}
```

Any idea how to fix that?

Comment: TextView tv =  (TextView) super.getChildView(groupPosition, childPosition, isLastChild,convertView, parent);

This line is returning an object of TwoLineListItem which you are trying to cast to TextView which is wrong... Make and Object of TwoLineListItem and than return that object from getView

Comment: I make TextView tv = ((TextView) super.getChildView(groupPosition, childPosition, isLastChild,convertView, parent).findViewById(android.R.id.text1)); but text2 disappear. How to manage those 2 TextView?

Comment: try setting some text in the secondTextview

Comment: TextView tv = ((TextView) super.getChildView(groupPosition, childPosition, isLastChild,convertView, parent).findViewById(android.R.id.text1));
                     TextView tv2 = ((TextView) super.getChildView(groupPosition, childPosition, isLastChild,convertView, parent).findViewById(android.R.id.text2)); And I am trying to return both tv, but don't know how.

Comment: I have posted and asnwer, check if it works for you. If not please state the exact requirement

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found a solution:

```
final View itemRenderer = super.getChildView(groupPosition, childPosition, isLastChild, convertView, parent);
                        final TextView tv1 = (TextView)itemRenderer.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
                        final TextView tv2 = (TextView)itemRenderer.findViewById(android.R.id.text2);
                        tv2.setTextColor(0xff0000ff);
                        return itemRenderer;
```

Answer (score 0):

As the comments say, you're casting a TwoLineListItem to a TextView. As shown in the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TwoLineListItem.html), you can use `getText1()` or `getText2()` to get the separate textviews.

```
TwoLineListItem tlli = (TwoLineListItem) super.getChildView(..);
TextView tv1 = tlli.getText1(); // get the first TextView
TextView tv2 = tlli.getText2(); // get the second TextView, if you want it
// Here you can change the text colours
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    try {
        mAdapter = new SimpleExpandableListAdapter(
            this,
            groupData,
            android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_2,
            new String[] { FIRST, SECOND },
            new int[] { android.R.id.text1, android.R.id.text2 },
            childData,
            android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_2,
            new String[] { FIRST, SECOND },
            new int[] { android.R.id.text1, android.R.id.text2 }){
                @Override
                public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition,
                        boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

                    TwoLineListItem tv =  (TwoLineListItem ) super.getChildView(groupPosition, childPosition, isLastChild,convertView, parent);
    final TextView tv1 = (TextView)tv.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
                            final TextView tv2 = (TextView)tv.findViewById(android.R.id.text2);
tv1.setText("TextView1");
tv2.setText("TextView2");
                    //change color text of tv here
                    //tv.setTextColor(0xff00ff00);
                    return tv;
                }
        };
        setListAdapter(mAdapter);
        getExpandableListView().setOnChildClickListener(this);
    }
    catch(Exception exc) {
        Log.e("Log", exc.toString());
    }
```